# Read data from all rows from Oracle and display in textbox using C#

Tags: c#, oracle

I have Oracle data like this:

[image]

The table is named **KETERANGAN** and I want those data in textBox1. Not just one row but all rows. This my code used **OracleDataReader**

```
OracleCommand cmd = new OracleCommand();
OracleDataReader dr;
cmd.CommandText = @"SELECT NOTES FROM KETERANGAN";
cmd.Connection = koneksidb.con;
dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
while (dr.Read())
{
    textBox1.Text = dr["NOTES"].toString();
}
dr.Close();
```

I get: **You're Cool**.

I want: **You're Cool, Amazing, Wonderful**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

use `+=` instead of `=` which will append the result. you are currently replacing it.

```
OracleCommand cmd = new OracleCommand();
OracleDataReader dr;
cmd.CommandText = @"SELECT NOTES FROM KETERANGAN";
cmd.Connection = koneksidb.con;
dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
while (dr.Read())
{
    textBox1.Text += dr["NOTES"].toString() + ",";
}
dr.Close();
```

Comment: yes, you're right. just adding + and it solve, i never image it exactly so easy,..many thanks

Answer (score 2):

It could be done like this:

```
  // wrap IDisposable into using
  using (OracleCommand cmd = new OracleCommand()) {  
    cmd.Connection = koneksidb.con;

    // Make SQL readable
    cmd.CommandText = 
      @"SELECT Notes 
          FROM Keterangan";

    // wrap IDisposable into using; do not close manually - dr.Close()
    using (OracleDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader()) {
      // do not append string in loop - use SringBuilder
      StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(); 

      while (dr.Read()) {
        if (sb.Length > 0) // <- do not put delimiter before the very first item
          sb.Append(", "); // <- do you want a delimiter? Say, comma?

        // ".ToString()" provides debug info, use Convert.ToString() instead
        sb.Append(Convert.ToString(dr.GetValue(0))); 
      }  

      // Assign data once in order to prevent re-painting (and blinking)
      textBox1.Text = sb.ToString();
    } 
  }
```

Hope, the comments inside the routine explain the code enough.

Comment: thanks for your suggest, but i have solve it by adding + in my code like suggest answer that i have voted

Comment: @aminvincent: wrap at least `IDisposable` into `using` in your solution :) otherwise you'll have *resource leakage*.

Answer (score 2):

Safe and optimized solution...

```
var notesBuilder = new StringBuilder();

const string SQL = @"SELECT NOTES FROM KETERANGAN";
using (var cmd = new OracleCommand(SQL, koneksidb.con))
{
  using (OracleDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader())
  {
    while (dr.Read())
    {
      notesBuilder.Append(dr["NOTES"]);
      notesBuilder.AppendLine(",");
    }
  }
}

textBox1.Text = notesBuilder.ToString();
```

Comment: thanks for your suggest, but i have solve it by adding + in my code like suggest answer that i have voted

Comment: @aminvincent If your table has many rows, you may have a performance issue using + with strings (which recreates a new string instance for each concatenation)

Comment: i will try first for your code above,.. if it success for many datas i will use it. thank your suggest

Answer (score 1):

Or you can set the `Multiline` property on your textbox to true and use

```
textBox1.Lines.Add(dr["NOTES"].toString());
```

Comment: thanks for your suggest, but i have solve it by adding + in my code like suggest answer that i have voted